# EKS coredns resolve eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-eks, eks

Can't resolve eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Server:         10.100.0.10
Address:        10.100.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: No answer
```

eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com can resolve

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Server:         10.100.0.10
Address:        10.100.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 18.224.106.105
Name:   eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 3.19.160.93
Name:   eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 3.140.46.29
```

resolv.conf:

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ec2.internal
nameserver 10.100.0.10
options ndots:5
```

Any other domain names are able to resolve. coredns was restarted several times. DNS logs shows no error:

```
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:51752 - 22291 "A IN eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local. udp 76 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 169 0.0001556s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:33663 - 37137 "A IN eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.svc.cluster.local. udp 63 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 156 0.000135843s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:50667 - 58897 "A IN eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.cluster.local. udp 59 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 152 0.000123039s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:41309 - 7908 "A IN eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.ec2.internal. udp 58 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 143 0.001021025s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:36954 - 39742 "A IN eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. udp 45 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 159 0.000406734s


[INFO] 192.168.151.19:52190 - 59843 "A IN eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.svc.cluster.local. udp 63 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 156 0.000131496s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:50557 - 40144 "A IN eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.ec2.internal. udp 58 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 143 0.001338827s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:34010 - 19930 "A IN eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local. udp 76 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 169 0.000125443s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:44829 - 17889 "A IN eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.cluster.local. udp 59 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 152 0.000123845s
[INFO] 192.168.151.19:50894 - 26393 "A IN eks.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. udp 45 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 174 0.00135709

I followed this recommendations to debug DNS resolution https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/.
Restarted coredns several times
```

I expect DNS name to be resolved by internal DNS the same way as google DNS:

```
kubectl exec -n unum-staging -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 44.212.119.1
Name:   eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 35.174.140.209
Name:   eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 184.73.163.135
```

Can you please advise me how to fix that issue? EKS Kubernetes version 1.29

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.